# How to pass correctly a UITextlabel's value to another view

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard

I have a `UITableView` that using a custom table view cell, the cell contains a `UITextLabel` and a `UIButton`. I would like to pass the the textlabel's value to the another view when the `UIButton` tapped. I'm using a segue called `goToNewView` to pass the data. In the destination view controller i have a button that should display an `NSLog` with the passed value when the `dataTestButton` tapped. Actually i'm getting no errors, when i tap the `dataTestButton`, but the desired data (from the `mySimpleContactUsernameLabel`) does not appears. Only the `The string =` shown up.

I'm sure that something in my `prepareForSegue` method is incorrect, but i couldn't figure out how to tell to the method, that i wanna pass the data from the same label where the button was pressed. So i would really appreciate if somebody could show me the right way.

Here's the code of the view controller from where i want to pass the data:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.simpleContact = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"simpleContact"];

}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {


    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    PFQuery *queryMyContacts = [self.simpleContact query];
    [queryMyContacts orderByAscending:@"username"];
    [queryMyContacts findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        else {
            self.allMyContact = objects;  

              [tableViewTwo reloadData];
    }
}];
}
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   return [self.allMyContact count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    CustomTableCell *cell = [tableViewTwo dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"devCell"];
    PFUser *user = [self.allMyContact objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.mySimpleContactUsernameLabel.text = user.username;

    return cell;
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"goToNewView"]) {
        if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[NewDestinationViewController class]]) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableViewTwo indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NewDestinationViewController *dataToNew = [segue destinationViewController];
            dataToNew.messageRecipient = [self.allMyContact objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the destination view controller's .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (IBAction)dataTestButton:(id)sender {

    NSString *messageRecipient = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSLog (@"The string = %@", messageRecipient);
}
```

.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *messageRecipient;
- (IBAction)dataTestButton:(id)sender;
```

Comment: Check `[self.allMyContact objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` before passing it to your next ViewController.

Comment: @Larme what do you mean exactly on "check `[self.allMyContact objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` before passing.." Is the problem with this part?

Comment: Log it before you set this value to `dataToNew.messageRecipient`.

Comment: No matter what you do NSLog will always print only "The string =". Because you just created a new instance of NSString called "messageRecipient", which is empty when you print it.

Comment: @Larme  The log displays always the first row's content. No matter which button i tap.

Comment: @x4h1d i should use `self.messageRecipient` and delete the `NSString *messageRecipient = [[NSString alloc] init];`?

Comment: yes, that's the point.

Comment: @x4h1d now i can pass the data, but it passes always the first label from the table view. Do you have any idea how can i send the label from the same cell where the button was tapped?

Comment: @sabin, prepareForSegue is not a good idea in this case. I suggest you to implement tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and inside that method implement feature pass the object rather than using prepareForSegue. By the way, don't alloc destination view controller every time. I believe it's a single view controller you call every time. So alloc it in more secure place.

Comment: Thanks, actually I'm using the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: with a segue, i've removed the button, but I will try it without segue too. What do you mean on secure place? Is there any security issues with segues that cause problems?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use this small library to help you out with table segues (I hope you're familiar with CocoaPods)

https://github.com/stefanomondino/SMQuickSegue

If you you have a cell segue to the next view controller, it should be possible achieve your goal with this

```
#import <UIViewController+SMQuickSegue.h>

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CustomTableCell *cell = [tableViewTwo dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"devCell"];
PFUser *user = [self.allMyContact objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.mySimpleContactUsernameLabel.text = user.username;
[cell setSegueParameters:@{@"messageRecipient":user.name}]; //will set messageRecipient on the destination view controller with the name property of user.
return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
    [self quickPrepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately i can not use CocoaPods actually because Parse is a bit buggy with it.

Comment: You can also use it without cocoapods, just clone the library and drag the two files (UIViewController+SMQuickSegue.h and UIViewController+SMQuickSegue.m) in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when you alloc the local variable `messageRecipient` you are then not reading the property you declared in your header file.

Change your destination method to this, and it should work (Assuming you are using auto synthesis for your properties)...

```
- (IBAction)dataTestButton:(id)sender {

    NSLog (@"The string = %@", _messageRecipient);

}
```